# How do I resume booting process after sulogin procedure

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I upgraded Arch Linux today and systemd stopped booting again. So I logged in with sulogin, mounted the drive.

How do I resume the booting process? Like in old days, `init 3` somethings like that.

Answer (score 3):

Just exit the shell: do an `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Should there not be some investigation as to what the error is, why systemd stops ? How would one step back to a lower run-level or can one only continue ?

Comment: If it drops to a single-user prompt during the boot sequence, you're already at the lowest runlevel.  At that point it only makes sense either to continue the boot sequence or reboot the system.

Comment: That's the sort of explanation that would help your answer. What more could you add to make it clear and provide the OP with a choice what to do next ?

Comment: I assumed the OP knows why (he 'mounted the drive') -- so I just answered the bare question he asked.

Comment: Exactly, so how would the OP resume the boot sequence? You answer only tells how to stop it. The OP has manually mounted the drive so presumably is already at a shell and is looking for the systemd equivalent of `init 3`.

Comment: I took it that the OP did a normal boot, it failed in some way and dropped to an sulogin prompt.  He logged in and fixed the problem.  If he now exits the sulogin shell, the boot process will attempt to resume.